# Fetching html element from src using webrequest and substring + indexof

Tags: c#, substring, httpwebrequest, indexof

Hello overflow community,

I have a little problem. I wrote a Class which is just a simple get request with the parameters for a url, the referer and the cookies afterwards it returns the pagesrc which is the message for my fetch string function which has a message, start and stop parameter.

Here is the Class :

```
class HttpMethods
{
    public static string Fetch(string url, string referer, ref CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.UserAgent = "" ;
        request.Referer = referer;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies.Add(response.Cookies);


        string pageSrc;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSrc = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return pageSrc;
    }

}
```

An this is my main function :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        CookieContainer myCookies = new CookieContainer();
        string myStr = HttpMethods.Fetch("localhost", "localhost", ref myCookies);
        void fetchStr (string message , string start, string stop)
        {
            int startIndex = message.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
            int stopIndex = message.IndexOf(stop);
            Console.Write( message.Substring(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex) );
        }

        fetchStr(myStr, "I am a String ", " to fetch");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Everything works fine when i fetch ONLY plaintext but when i want to fetch a element, it returns me the lenght can not be less than 0 thats the response when some string wasnt found.

this is really weird here is an example :

```
            //Original Sentence : I am a string please fetch me dude.
        fetchStr(myStr, "I am a ", " fetch me dude");
```

This will return : string please

But when i try to fetch this part :

```
            //Original Sentence : name="_playerToken" value="a8276964-fdac-4d63-ae25-5752f157a21b" />
        fetchStr(myStr, "name=\"_playerToken\" value=\"", "\"/>");
```

This will return lenght can not be less than 0 .

Here is a Screenshot of my visual studio output :

[Visual Studio Value Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB4G1.png)

Does someone have an idea where the problem could be ?

Comment: As a little note: `request.CookieContainer = cookies;` is enough for the cookie handling; `cookies.Add(response.Cookies);` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Completely changing my original answer as just noticed you are trying to get /> from a whole html output, therefore returning the first instance that it sees rather than the one after the _playerToken key.

I would suggest changing your fetchStr method to a regex query instead.

```
String regex = "name=\"_playerToken\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"";
var match = Regex.Matches(message, regex);
if (match.Count > 0)
{
    string result = match[0].Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Die Länge darf nicht kleiner als 0 (null) sein.
Parametername: length" :( but stopIndex is 11705 now

Comment: What using statements do i need for regex ? i have never used it i get errors in my vstudio

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions

If you copy the code in my answer you will get the expected result, I have just tried myself

Comment: Damn you are my hero bro ! can u explain me this : "([^\"]*)\"" please ?

Comment: No worries It basically gets any string after value=" which is not a " until it hits another ". Please mark my answer and correct if it has solved your issue :)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much :) is there any way to safe the result of fetchStr (this one : string result = match[0].Groups[1].Value; ) into another variable so i can use the token in another function ?

Comment: Just have your fetchStr function return a string value instead

Comment: Can u give me an example pls return doesnt work in void